# POST Request to Django Backend from Flutter/Dart

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart, post

I am trying to make a POST Request from my Flutter Frontend to my Django Backend, I am using DIO. The Error I get is:

> **Bad Request: /api/homeapi/Users/
> [20/Jun/2023 18:16:38] "POST /api/homeapi/Users/ HTTP/1.1" 400 58**

This is my Code:

**serializer.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Brand, User


class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Brand
    fields = [
      'imgURL',
      'brand_name'
    ]

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
      'email',
      'selected_colors'
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
class BrandViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except ValidationError as e:
            return Response({'errors': e.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Models.py**:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    imgURL = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120)
    selected_colors = models.JSONField()
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Brands', BrandViewSet, basename='brand')
router.register('Users', UserViewSet, basename='User')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/homeapi/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/get-csrf-token/', get_csrf_token, name='get-csrf-token'),
]
```

This is my Dart Code:
**api.dart**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

const dataUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/homeapi/Brands/';

Future<void> postData(String url, Map<String, dynamic> fields) async {
  final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  
  try {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers, body: json.encode(fields)); // Convert fields to JSON string
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Request was successful
      print('POST request successful');
      print(response.body);
    } else {
      // Request failed
      print('POST request failed');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Exception occurred during the request
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

register.dart:

```
Future<void> addUserDetails(String email) async {
    postData(userURL, {
      "email": email
    });
  }
```

> I really don't know what to do I tried including the CSRF Token, but that doesn't
> worked too. Im really appreciate any help :D

Comment: Try changing the DefaultRouter to `router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)` in your **urls.py**.  You might also need to change your **settings.py** with `APPEND_SLASH=False`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using dio, you are using http. However, did you try to send requests on postman?, I don't have experience in Django.
Using dio will make your life easier. Using dio should look like:

```
class DioHelper {
  static late Dio dio;

  static init() {
    dio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',
        receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
      ),
    );
  }
  static Future<Response> addUserDetails(
      {required String token, required String email}) async {
    return await dio.post(
      //your URL
      'homeapi/Brands/',
      //your data
      data: {'email': email},
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          //if your backend require authorization
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        followRedirects: false,
        validateStatus: (status) {
          //to see the status code
          print(status);
          return true;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the point is that is to make this class help you in your requests, so add all the requests you need as methods here.
you call `DioHelper.init()` in your `main` function to insure that it's initialized.